# In STM32 the timers are connected to which bus?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, arm, stm32cubeide, cortex-m7

I am using STM32H723ZG and in our application, I wanted to know to which bus (APB1 or APB2) the timers are connected. I need these detail, as I have to configure the timer to that particular bus's frequency.

I have read in an article where the timer bus matrices were given but the same could not be found in the datasheet.

Comment: You don't check the timer registers for that. You check the APB registers. They contain the bit that enables the clock for each peripheral connected to the bus.

Comment: Tip for working with microcontrollers: if you don’t know something, check the datasheet and the reference manual. The answer is often somewhere in either of those. Sometimes both.

Answer (score 4):

The details of which peripheral is on which bus are in datasheet page 16, Figure 1 called Block Diagram.

Answer (score 2):

Judging by the register mapping ([RM0468](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00603761-stm32h723733-stm32h725735-and-stm32h730-value-line-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf) pages 137-139), TIM1, TIM8, and TIM15-TIM17 are on APB2, while TIM2-TIM7, TIM12-TIM14 and TIM23-TIM24 are on APB1.